# How to mount overlay filesystem over root folder in linux?

Tags: linux, root, mount, chroot

I want to mount an overlay filesystem over the root folder.

My commands are:

```
mkdir -p merged upper work
sudo mount -t overlay ovr -o index=off -o lowerdir=\,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged
```

I get the error

> mount: /.../merged: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ovr_, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I made this to work already but I don't know exactly what I did different from this.

Answer (score 0):

(probably a necrobump)

1. try without `index=off`
2. the merged dir is where the files go, so set that as root too (`/`)
3. lowerdir is set to `'escape sequence'` not `'file path'` i.e. `\` not `/`

if that fails, it could be all sorts of things, bad `mount` binary, goofy kernel, something else...

also check `dmesg`, sure helped me when I tried to figure out what was wrong ('uper' typo), also try busybox mount, you'll have to install that, most likely (it doesn't come with most distros)